Is all of Vedas (Samhita, Brahmana, Aranyaka and Upanishad) supposed to be completely infallible (errorless), authorless and eternal?
I have heard of the concept of Apaurasheya, being authorless, and that all of the six astika Darsanas considered Vedas either infallible or eternal or authorless. My question is, does that apply to all of Vedas or some portion of Vedas? Someone told me, who is a Mimamsa scholar, that Mimamsa considers only Brahmanas to be infallible, eternal and authorless, not the Samhitas or Upanishads. He said Vedantins consider Upanishads to be infallible, authorless and eternal and not the rest of the Vedas. I have heard others say everything in Vedas are infallible, eternal and authorless. I have heard Vaishnavites say that with Vedas, Gita and Bhagavad Purana is also infallible. I have heard some say that Adi Shankaracharya and Ramanujacharya differed on this, where Adi Shankara thought only some parts of Vedas were true, while Ramanujacharya considered all parts were true. So, which one is true? Is there any consensus? Or does different sects believe in different levels or parts of infallibility?
